pass shell variable to -A flag in grep
I have a set of .sdf (molecular) files that have varying numbers of atomic coordinates that I need to grep out. The header information of the file provides the number of atoms in the file along with a unique regex that I can use in grep, like below:
 42 44  0  0  1  0            999 V2000
   39.2345   17.6631   12.7846 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.3521   17.1021   12.7361 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.1778   17.2187   11.8038 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   40.7693   16.2193   13.9145 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.0927   15.7293   13.7433 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.5145   14.9212   14.7395 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.1856   13.5746   14.8668 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.2068   12.6501   13.5170 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.6245   12.9340   16.0147 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.3443   11.5877   16.4784 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.3652   10.7569   16.9470 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.0859    9.4573   17.3660 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.7792    8.9724   17.3118 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.7401    9.7888   16.8448 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.3981    9.3768   16.7741 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   38.9977    7.9742   16.7120 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.0447    7.4076   15.2989 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2643    7.0598   14.7072 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2940    6.5235   13.4197 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.1061    6.3134   12.7236 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.8875    6.6562   13.3069 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.8553    7.2050   14.5894 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.0347   11.0942   16.4477 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.6360   14.0254   16.9149 S   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.3652   15.3253   15.7666 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.0487   16.6108   16.0384 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.8748   17.5611   15.2449 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.7784   16.7153   17.0499 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   40.7112   16.7969   14.8381 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.0553   15.3978   13.9950 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.3838   11.1152   16.9827 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.8828    8.8262   17.7310 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.5909    7.9603   17.6367 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   38.6574   10.0626   16.8096 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.6610    7.3813   17.3429 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.9898    7.8713   17.1160 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.1892    7.2050   15.2463 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.2390    6.2704   12.9621 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.1291    5.8845   11.7326 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   36.9665    6.4969   12.7658 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   36.9062    7.4739   15.0296 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2333   11.7381   16.1154 H   0  0  0  0  0  0

I have defined a variable to pass to grep in the -A flag so that I can specify the number of lines to output after finding my regular expression:
export no_atoms=`grep V2000 *.sdf | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $no_atoms 
42

However, when I try to pass this variable to the -A flag in grep, I am stuck:
grep -A{$no_atoms} *.sdf
grep: {42}: invalid context length argument
grep -A\$no_atoms *.sdf
grep: $no_atoms: invalid context length argument
grep -A\{$no_atoms} *.sdf
grep: {42}: invalid context length argument
grep -A\[$no_atoms] *.sdf
grep: [42]: invalid context length argument
grep -A[$no_atoms] *.sdf
grep: [42]: invalid context length argument
grep -A"$no_atoms" *.sdf
^C
grep -A\"$no_atoms" *.sdf
> ^C

I know this has to be something simple, but most of the references I have found online refer to passing a shell variable on as a regex in grep, not as a variable to a flag.

The $ goes outside the braces. grep -A${no_atoms} *.sdf

Also, you need something to search for: grep -A${no_atoms} 'search_string' *.sdf —— without that, the expansion of *.sdf makes the filename of the first matched file the search text, which is then searched for in the rest of the .sdf files: grep <args> one.sdf two.sdf.  If there's one match that one filename is taken as the search string, but no files to search are specified: grep <args> foo.sdf so standard input is searched. If no files match the command becomes grep <args> which gives me a usage message on standard error (stderr)

@StephenP thanks for the clarification and catching my lack of a search string (totally missed that). After testing your solution
grep -A${no_atoms} V2000 *.sdf outputs all of my coordinate lines. Syntax!

Also, -A"$no_atoms" does what you are asking. The lack of a search string would have resulted in the first match from the wildcard being used as the search string in all the other files; maybe the symptoms you are seeing indicates that you have no files matching *.sdf

awk alone can handle this task, there is no need to grep | awk and then another grep to get your results.
You may use:
awk -v s='V2000' '$NF == s {n=$1} NR > n+1 {exit} 1' file

 42 44  0  0  1  0            999 V2000
   39.2345   17.6631   12.7846 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.3521   17.1021   12.7361 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.1778   17.2187   11.8038 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   40.7693   16.2193   13.9145 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.0927   15.7293   13.7433 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.5145   14.9212   14.7395 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.1856   13.5746   14.8668 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.2068   12.6501   13.5170 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.6245   12.9340   16.0147 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   42.3443   11.5877   16.4784 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.3652   10.7569   16.9470 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.0859    9.4573   17.3660 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.7792    8.9724   17.3118 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.7401    9.7888   16.8448 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.3981    9.3768   16.7741 N   0  0  0  0  0  0
   38.9977    7.9742   16.7120 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.0447    7.4076   15.2989 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2643    7.0598   14.7072 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2940    6.5235   13.4197 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.1061    6.3134   12.7236 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.8875    6.6562   13.3069 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.8553    7.2050   14.5894 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.0347   11.0942   16.4477 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.6360   14.0254   16.9149 S   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.3652   15.3253   15.7666 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.0487   16.6108   16.0384 C   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.8748   17.5611   15.2449 O   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.7784   16.7153   17.0499 O   0  5  0  0  0  0
   40.7112   16.7969   14.8381 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.0553   15.3978   13.9950 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   44.3838   11.1152   16.9827 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   43.8828    8.8262   17.7310 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.5909    7.9603   17.6367 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   38.6574   10.0626   16.8096 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.6610    7.3813   17.3429 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   37.9898    7.8713   17.1160 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.1892    7.2050   15.2463 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   41.2390    6.2704   12.9621 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   39.1291    5.8845   11.7326 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   36.9665    6.4969   12.7658 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   36.9062    7.4739   15.0296 H   0  0  0  0  0  0
   40.2333   11.7381   16.1154 H   0  0  0  0  0  0


Thanks for the quick response -- another case where I need to utilize awk more often. I am following the syntax in the first part of your awk one-liner, but can you explain to me what the second half is doing?
NR > n+1 {exit} 1

NR > n+1 {exit} tells awk to exit the program when current record number is greater than n+1 where n is 42 (we captured in first condition. And finally 1 is for printing each record from record number 1 to 43.
